# Function name for setting all nonzeros to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

For the purposes of a naming convention,

what is the name for the mathamatical function that, given a sparse matrix $M$, sets all non-zero values in $M$ to 1, and leaves the matrix otherwise unchanged?

It's like the indicator function, or the Kronecker delta (except instead of an equality, it is a 1 if not equal to j, 0 otherwise--where j is 0)...

But I don't remember what it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do $x=|\operatorname{sgn}(x)|,$ the signum function, defined by
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x>0\\ 0, &x=0\\-1,&x<0\end{cases}.$$
Warning, though: if you're doing this numerically, testing for a double number equal to zero has issues. Probably best to test if a number is within machine epsilon of zero.

Comment: ah, an "absolute_signum(X)" would do it--thanks!  (was writing nonzero_to_ones, and figured I might as well leave the code syntax the way it was at that point)-- will accept when timer runs out